# How to make 2 sections side by side on Elementor Pro Page Builder

Tags: css, flexbox, elementor

I'm trying to make two sections side by side in elementor pagebuilder.
What i have done so far
Created a section (section 1) added css

```
selector {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

On the second section (section-2) i tried the css the same as above with flex property. But didn't work as expected

```
selector {
max-width:50%;
display:flex;
float:right:
}
```

[attaching image of what i'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2rs1.png)

So i'm trying make left side section title and right side for content kind of layout.
Could anyone help me ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the HTML as well?

Comment: If you need both left and right sections the same height, you can set `display: flex` on the parent element of the sections, remove floats and add `flex: 1 1 50%` on the sections. Some html of yours would be useful too.